# LaTeX like Math.SE

Tags: fonts, formatting, packages

I quite like how the Mathematics Stackexchange site's LaTeX looks, and I know that they have a LaTeX functionality by running MathJax on the site. What fonts/packages are available to achieve this look?

[example question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182611/convergent-subsequence-in-mathbb-r/182612#182612)

Comment: The mathematics seem to use the very default LaTeX setting: default font (CM/LM), default size (if that can be measured on a web-page etc. I'm not sure whether this answers your question, because I'm not sure that we can speak about "packages" in connection with MathJax.

Comment: @tohecz This might be system-dependent. When I right-click on the linked MathJax and take a look at 'about' I get 'using local STIX fonts'.

Comment: @JosephWright "Firefox v3.5.15 — otf fonts" in my case. This means that there's no single answer to the question...

Comment: I think maybe even browswer dependent.  Things look quite differently for me on all these stackexchange websites depending on whether I'm using [conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) (Mozilla-based) or, say, Chromium (which gives me annoying capitals for TeX.SE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As MathJax renders the output locally, the visual appearance is system-dependent. You can see what fonts are being used by right-clicking on the MathJax and choosing 'About MathJax'. For example, in my case I get 'using local STIX fonts' (amongst other things), which makes sense as I have these installed in my system tree. On the other hand, tohecz reports 'otf fonts', presumably Computer Modern or Latin Modern math fonts.

---

Checking the [MathJax font help](http://www.mathjax.org/help-v2/fonts/), it says

> MathJax will use the STIX fonts if they are installed on your
>   computer.  This will improve MathJax’s speed when it typesets the
>   mathematics on any page, so it is to your advantage to download and
>   install one of these fonts, though MathJax will still work even if you
>   don’t install the fonts yourself.

To use STIX, I would probably favour using the [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package with XeTeX or LuaTeX, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}
\begin{document}
$y = mx + c$
\end{document}
```

although to be honest the [XITS bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/xits) is probably a better bet at present.